# Date difference with refined ETA results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I’m trying to set my output to “*Date not confirmed*” if the date from MySQL = 2013-12-25 & $daydiff = ‘any’ and output “*Not available*” if the MySQL date = “NULL” & and $daydiff = ‘any’

**My code**

```
$ArrivalDate = $variants_data['ArrivalDate'];

$daydiff=floor((abs(strtotime(date("Y-m-d")) - strtotime($ArrivalDate))/(60*60*24)));

if ( $daydiff = ''  AND $ArrivalDate ='2013-12-25') {
    $ETA ='Date Not Confirmed';
}

elseif ( $daydiff = ''  AND $ArrivalDate ='NULL') {
    $ETA ='Not available';
}

elseif ( $daydiff < '0') {
    $ETA ='';
}
elseif ( $daydiff < '31' ) {
    $ETA ='Within 30 days';
}

elseif ( $daydiff > '31' ) {
    $ETA ='1 Month';
}

elseif ( $daydiff < '60' )  {
    $ETA ='2 Months';
}

elseif ( $daydiff < '90' ) {
    $ETA ='3 Months';
}

elseif ( $daydiff < '121' ) {
    $ETA ='4 Months';
}

elseif ( $daydiff < '152' ) {
    $ETA ='5 Months';
}

elseif ( $daydiff < '182' ) {
    $ETA ='6 Months';
}

elseif ( $daydiff < '213' ) {
    $ETA ='7 Months';
}

elseif ( $daydiff < '245' ) {
    $ETA ='8 Months';
}

elseif ( $daydiff < '274' ) {
    $ETA ='9 Months';
}

elseif ( $daydiff < '304' ) {
    $ETA ='10 Months';
}

elseif ( $daydiff < '334' ) {
    $ETA ='11 Months';
}

elseif ( $daydiff < '365' ) {
    $ETA ='12 Months';
}

else
{
$ETA ='Not Applicable';
}
```

So far the code doesn’t give me required results, when did I go wrong?

Comment: What results do you get, what are your inputs, and what results are you expecting for those inputs?

Comment: One correction... $daydiff == ''  AND $ArrivalDate == '2013-12-25', $daydiff == ''  AND $ArrivalDate == 'NULL'

Comment: @Crontab the results are called by the ETA depending on the value we get from $daydiff. Input is $ArrivalDate of which it gets info from MySQL less current date. There is a specific date on MySQL that simply says there is "Date not confirms" and that date is 2013-12-25 and "NULL" means there is no ETA, the product has reached the store and no expected orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon re-reading, I noticed that you use the assignment operator (`=`) for your initial comparisons.  You should be using the equality operator (`==`) instead.  Your first couple of conditionals should read:

```
if ( $daydiff == '' && $ArrivalDate == '2013-12-25') {
    $ETA ='Date Not Confirmed';
} elseif ( $daydiff == '' && $ArrivalDate == 'NULL') {
    $ETA ='Not available';
}
```

Also, could `$ArrivalDate` be set to a **string** value of `"NULL"` or do you mean `NULL` as in nothing?

Comment: I forget to check for that all the time too. It just looks "right" lol

Comment: @Syndrose It's definitely one of those things that's easy to miss!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably usually getting 1 month as your ETA for anything 1 month or longer?
try adding multiple conditions to you elseif statements, because your first elseif statement will always be true after 31 days. so something like..

```
elseif ( $daydiff > 30 && $daydiff < 60 ) { // anything between 31 and 59 days is 1 month
$ETA ='1 Month';
}

elseif ( $daydiff > 60 && $daydiff < 90  )  { // anything between 61 and 89 days is 2 months
$ETA ='2 Months';
}
```

and so on...

Comment: thanks for input but the code doesn't work. It gives no results